# Cross-sectional data with fixed effects

Tags: fixed-effects-model

In the experimental design, using cross-sectional data to generate OLS regression, after controlling the individual observed characters such as job title, is there any problem adding individual fixed effects?  The purpose of adding individual effects is to control unobserved characters to avoid the OVB issue.

Comment: Thank you, Michael.